# 2.2 ecotec on 2008 Cobalt - Timing chain tensioner will not come out of head

Tags: cobalt, ecotec

Asked this on a message board, no luck.

Got an odd one for you here. My mom's Cobalt started having the notorious ticking around 100k. Went and installed a new timing chain tensioner. I misread the directions and thought I had to bang on the tensioner with a screwdriver to release it, I wailed on it good enough that I put a really bad gouge in the tensioner body (it was late, I was tired...  ) So I went and ordered another tensioner...

Fast forward a few days. I'm trying to pull the newly installed/screwed up tensioner out. I'm cranking away on it, and it's slowly turning out until it just... spins without coming out at all (edit: I think it's pertinent to note that it doesn't spin freely, exactly. It's tough. I'm using a 24" 1/2 drive flex ratchet with a 1 1/4" socket and it takes a little bit of elbow grease to turn it, but it's not like you're trying to break it loose or anything. Just takes some force)

Now, I'm not a dummy. I was an aircraft mechanic for 6 years and I'm currently an industrial air compressor mechanic. I know my way around tools and metals and fasteners and threading, etc. But this one just has me absolutely stumped.

There are about 4 1/2 threads showing, the O-ring is freely moving. I've tried getting a screwdriver in there to try to put some force against it while I turn it. Nothing. I've beat the hell out of it. It was easy going in, I threaded it in by hand and tightened it with a ratchet and it was fine. There is no sign of galding or any other anomaly with the threads. It just spins, and spins, and will not come out. It's stuck in there. Even with a 48" crowbar.

It won't even thread back in.

Any experiences or ideas with this one?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if your bolt has taken the threads with it and are now spinning in the block ... I've not dealt with this one before though. Hopefully someone else has.